# if_attribute doesn't work with multiple hash on declarative_authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, declarative-authorization

I use declarative_authorization on Ruby on rails 3.1.

A group has many albums (groupalbum), a group is create by one user (user_id in foreign key for group table).
Only the owner of the group can create albums.

Here is my authorization_rules.rb :

```
has_permission_on [:group_albums], :to => [:create] do
    if_attribute :group =>  { :user => is_in { user.groups } }
end
```

Here is my GroupAlbumsControler :

```
class GroupAlbumsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :set_group_album_from_params, :only => :show
    before_filter :set_group_album_new, :only => [:index, :new]
    filter_access_to :all, :attribute_check => true
    (...)
end
```

But it doesn't work :

```
You are not allowed to access this action.
```

Even if I'm logged in with the owner of the group.

Where is my mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons why this isn't working.

Have you added :index and :new to your privileges?

```
privileges do
  privilege :manage, :includes => [:create, :read, :update, :delete]
  privilege :read, :includes => [:index, :show]
  privilege :create, :includes => :new
  privilege :update, :includes => :edit
  privilege :delete, :includes => :destroy
end
```

Have you a read permission on :group_albums for the current user?

```
has_permission_on [:group_albums], :to => [:create, :read] do
    if_attribute :group =>  { :user => is_in { user.groups } }
end
```

Which action do you call?